# Complex Newton's Method

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, complex-numbers

I'm trying to build a complex Newton's method. I've submitted a PR [here](https://github.com/boostorg/math/pull/165/files), where you can see the documentation and tests, as well as get a compiling example. I'd appreciate y'alls help reducing the workload on the maintainer.

This uses the idea that if x<sub>n</sub> converges to x*, then f(x*) = 0 whenever f' is continuous at x*. If f'(x<sub>n</sub>) = 0 at some point, it resorts to Muller's method.

```
#ifndef BOOST_NO_CXX11_AUTO_DECLARATIONS
/*
 * Why do we set the default maximum number of iterations to the number of digits in the type?
 * Because for double roots, the number of digits increases linearly with the number of iterations,
 * so this default should recover full precision even in this somewhat pathological case.
 * For isolated roots, the problem is so rapidly convergent that this doesn't matter at all.
 */
template<class Complex, class F>
Complex complex_newton(F g, Complex guess, int max_iterations=std::numeric_limits<typename Complex::value_type>::digits)
{
    typedef typename Complex::value_type Real;
    using std::norm;
    using std::abs;
    using std::max;
    // z0, z1, and z2 cannot be the same, in case we immediately need to resort to Muller's Method:
    Complex z0 = guess + Complex(1,0);
    Complex z1 = guess + Complex(0,1);
    Complex z2 = guess;

    do {
       auto pair = g(z2);
       if (norm(pair.second) == 0)
       {
           // Muller's method. Notation follows Numerical Recipes, 9.5.2:
           Complex q = (z2 - z1)/(z1 - z0);
           auto P0 = g(z0);
           auto P1 = g(z1);
           Complex qp1 = static_cast<Complex>(1)+q;
           Complex A = q*(pair.first - qp1*P1.first + q*P0.first);

           Complex B = (static_cast<Complex>(2)*q+static_cast<Complex>(1))*pair.first - qp1*qp1*P1.first +q*q*P0.first;
           Complex C = qp1*pair.first;
           Complex rad = sqrt(B*B - static_cast<Complex>(4)*A*C);
           Complex denom1 = B + rad;
           Complex denom2 = B - rad;
           Complex correction = (z1-z2)*static_cast<Complex>(2)*C;
           if (norm(denom1) > norm(denom2))
           {
               correction /= denom1;
           }
           else
           {
               correction /= denom2;
           }

           z0 = z1;
           z1 = z2;
           z2 = z2 + correction;
       }
       else
       {
           z0 = z1;
           z1 = z2;
           z2 = z2  - (pair.first/pair.second);
       }

       // See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017766/constructing-newton-iteration-converging-to-non-root
       // If f' is continuous, then convergence of x_n -> x* implies f(x*) = 0.
       // This condition approximates this convergence condition by requiring three consecutive iterates to be clustered.
       Real tol = max(abs(z2)*std::numeric_limits<Real>::epsilon(), std::numeric_limits<Real>::epsilon());
       bool real_close = abs(z0.real() - z1.real()) < tol && abs(z0.real() - z2.real()) < tol && abs(z1.real() - z2.real()) < tol;
       bool imag_close = abs(z0.imag() - z1.imag()) < tol && abs(z0.imag() - z2.imag()) < tol && abs(z1.imag() - z2.imag()) < tol;
       if (real_close && imag_close)
       {
           return z2;
       }

   } while(max_iterations--);

    // The idea is that if we can get abs(f) < eps, we should, but if we go through all these iterations
    // and abs(f) < sqrt(eps), then roundoff error simply does not allow that we can evaluate f to < eps
    // This is somewhat awkward as it isn't scale invariant, but using the Daubechies coefficient example code,
    // I found this condition generates correct roots, whereas the scale invariant condition discussed here:
    // https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/30597/defining-a-condition-number-and-termination-criteria-for-newtons-method
    // allows nonroots to be passed off as roots.
    auto pair = g(z2);
    if (abs(pair.first) < sqrt(std::numeric_limits<Real>::epsilon()))
    {
        return z2;
    }

    return {std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN(),
            std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN()};
}
#endif
```

Usage:

```
boost::math::tools::polynomial<std::complex<double>> p{{1,0}, {0, 0}, {1,0}};
std::complex<double> guess{1,1};
boost::math::tools::polynomial<std::complex<double>> p_prime = p.prime();
auto f = [&](std::complex<double> z) { return std::make_pair<std::complex<double>, std::complex<double>>(p(z), p_prime(z)); };
std::complex<double> root = complex_newton(f, guess);
```

For a more intense example usage, see [here](https://github.com/boostorg/math/blob/37336e2372e02fa0d2a8ced2313f6e6cbb21337e/example/daubechies_coefficients.cpp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see too much that needs improving. I'd suggest that the correction logic be simplified to:

```
       Complex denom1 = B + rad,
               denom2 = B - rad,
               correction = (z1-z2)*static_cast<Complex>(2)*C,
               denom_corr;
       if (norm(denom1) > norm(denom2))
           denom_corr = denom1;
       else
           denom_corr = denom2;

       z0 = z1;
       z1 = z2;
       z2 += correction/denom_corr;
```

Elsewhere, combine your types and use commas where there are multiple variable declarations. It's a stylistic choice, but I don't like to repeat myself.

And this:

```
z2 = z2  - (pair.first/pair.second);
```

should be

```
z2 -= pair.first/pair.second;
```

Order of operations still applies so you don't need parens, and use combined operation+assignment.